# How to check if elements of a list of strings in a pandas column are present in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame (showing values of one of the rows) as below.
In the annotation column, I have a list of strings which I want to check in the note_sentence column which contains sentences.

I used the below code to check the existence but it is unable to capture the existence of strings in the sentences.

```
df_feature_case_notes['Exists'] = df_feature_case_notes.apply(lambda x: 'Yes' if x['annotation'] in x['note_sentence'] else 'No',axis=1)
```

How can I fix my code?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

okay try this

```
df_feature_case_notes['Exists'] = [x[0] in x[1] for x in zip(df_feature_case_notes["annotation"], df_feature_case_notes["annotation"])]
```

Comment: none of the answers worked, getting an output of false only.

Comment: df_feature_case_notes['Exists'] = [x[0] in x[1] for x in zip(df_feature_case_notes["annotation"], df_feature_case_notes["annotation"])]

Comment: try this it working for me